# Web Serial API - Automatically read

Tags: javascript, html, serial-port

I'm using the Chrome Web Serial API and it works fine when I click on button and select the port manually. Now I want to select automatically the port (COM1) when open a page. I don't want click the button and select the port. Also, when I reload the page I lost connection to the port. Does anyone know how could I do that? Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

```js
    "use strict";
    class SerialScaleController {
        constructor() {
            this.encoder = new TextEncoder();
            this.decoder = new TextDecoder();
        }
        async init() {
            if ('serial' in navigator) {
                try {
                    console.log(navigator)
                    const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
                    await port.open({ baudRate: 9600 });
                    this.reader = port.readable.getReader();
                    let signals = await port.getSignals();
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.error('There was an error opening the serial port:', err);
                }
            }
            else {
                console.error('Web serial doesn\'t seem to be enabled in your browser. Try enabling it by visiting:');
                console.error('chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features');
                console.error('opera://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features');
                console.error('edge://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features');
            }
        }
        async read() {
            try {
                const readerData = await this.reader.read();
                console.log(readerData)
                return this.decoder.decode(readerData.value);
            }
            catch (err) {
                const errorMessage = `error reading data: ${err}`;
                console.error(errorMessage);
                return errorMessage;
            }
        }
    }

    const serialScaleController = new SerialScaleController();
    const connect = document.getElementById('connect-to-serial');
    const getSerialMessages = document.getElementById('get-serial-messages');

    connect.addEventListener('pointerdown', () => {
      serialScaleController.init();
    });

    getSerialMessages.addEventListener('pointerdown', async () => {
      getSerialMessage();
    });

    async function getSerialMessage() {
      document.querySelector("#serial-messages-container .message").innerText += await serialScaleController.read()
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Web Serial</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="serial-scale-div">
        <button class="btn" id="connect-to-serial">Connect with Serial Device</button>
  </div>

  <button id="get-serial-messages">Get serial messages</button>
  
  <div id="serial-messages-container">
    <div class="message"></div>
  </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the user has approved you once via requestPort(), then in future you can use getPorts() to get an array of ports you've previously had, something like this.

```
// CanPrompt is 1 if being called from user button click etc
// Or 0 if calling from serial.onconnect or page load checking for device

var port = null;
if (CanPrompt) {
    port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
} else {
    port = await navigator.serial.getPorts();
    if ((port !== null) && (Array.isArray(port)) && (port.length > 0)) {
        port = port[0];
    } else return;
}
await port.open({ baudRate: 19200 });
```

More background info can be found in a closed git issue https://github.com/WICG/serial/issues/131

Answer (score 0):

I believe one requirement of web serial is to require a [user interaction for security](https://web.dev/usb/) in addition to being delivered on a site that has TLS.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought about using a cookie as a 'persistent' setting?
IE https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Good luck!